# PHP cURL JSON API

Tags: php, json, api, curl

My API documentation says I need to enter the following cURL.

curl

```
 -H "Accept: application/json"
 -F grant_type=consumer_credentials 
 -F consumer_key=ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
 -F consumer_secret=123456789
 https://sandbox.apps.****.com/api/AccessToken
```

I've no idea what to do with the -F bits (nor what -F stands for!)
So I put them in as JSON post data.

I assume -H is header?

As a starting point I had this:

```
$data = array(
  "grant_type" => "consumer_credentials",
  "consumer_key" => "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN",
  "consumer_secret" => "123456789"
);

$str_data = json_encode($data);

$url_send ="https://sandbox.apps.****.com/api/AccessToken";

function sendPostData($url, $post){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));  
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
}

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
```

But all I get is a page that says error occurred. It should return JSON with login data.

Comment: Could `-F` be field perhaps, as in one of the required fields to post within `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?...

Comment: `man curl` would tell you what all the commandline args are... or even `curl --help`. And no, you're not doing this correctly. `-F` sets a post field key=value pair. you're just sending over a single nameless json string.

Comment: RTFM http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: I don't have access to the command line so I can't do man curl etc. but yes that manual page is helpful.  What do you mean I'm sending a single nameless string though? Apologies if this is basic but I'm struggling with it.

Comment: Is it incorrect to send json data as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc said, I was sending through json instead of normal field data.

I put in

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $str_data .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($str_data, '&');
```

instead of

```
$str_data = json_encode($data);
```

and it seems to be working now.

Thanks