# How to understand this API specification?

Tags: php, api, http

I am new to API request having only done one before.

Have been given a document with this info:

> You must authenticate with a username and key to perform any action with the API. Authentication details must be passed along with other variables in each
>   request.
>
> Request are to https://(URL) via HTTP(S) POST. Communication is in JSON, so please ensure your HTTP headers specify "application/json". We will return a HTTP status code of 200 (OK) for most requests but can also return 400 (Bad Request) or 403 (Forbidden/Authorisation Failed)

Then I am presented with code examples for all the endpoints, eg:

> **Sample Request**
>
> ```
> {
> "request": "GetAvailableServices",
> "username": "custTEST_api",
> "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> }
> ```
>
> **Response**
>
> ```
>  {
> "success": true,
>
> "available_services": {
> "IPECX": {
> "carrier_name": "TOLL IPEC",
> "service_name": "ROAD EXPRESS"
> },
> "IPECH": {
> "carrier_name": "TOLL IPEC",
> "service_name": "PRIORITY"
> },
> "GIBSONX": {
> "carrier_name": "GIBSON",
> "service_name": "ROAD EXPRESS"
> }
> },
> "error_code": null,
> "error_message": null
> ```

So this is different to the last API integration I did.

I have been provided the appropriate username and key.

I am trying to do this in PHP .. but not sure how to translate the above into a php document. I did my previous authorisations in curl to get JSON data. But just can't figure this one out.

If I could just get one request working I'd be alright, I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153186/php-curl-json-api) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179301/how-to-get-json-data-from-rest-api-by-php-curl)? I used [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+api+json+php) to find these.

Comment: Thanks @halfer .. that search helped a lot.
Got it working now!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.com.au/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n\"request\": 
\"GetAvailableServices\",\r\n\"username\": \"APIUSERNAME\",\r\n\"key\": 
\"APIKEY\"\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  "cache-control: no-cache",
  "content-type: application/json",
  "key: \"APIKEY\"",
  "request: \"GetAvailableServices\"",
  "username: \"INNOVATIVEAPI\""
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```